# Setting number of rows to be displayed for Multi line text in swt

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I am using following for TextArea

```
ToolBar bar = new ToolBar(box,SWT.NONE);
ToolItem item = new ToolItem(bar, SWT.SEPARATOR);
Text text = new Text(bar, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI);
item.setWidth(width);
item.setControl(text);

GridData data = new GridData();
data.verticalAlignment = SWT.CENTER;
data.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
data.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
text.setLayoutData(data);
```

I want to display a multi line text box, currently its accepting multi line text but showing only a single line at a time.

Any idea how to set the number of rows to be displayed ?

Thanks.

Comment: what about using TextArea? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html

Comment: @chahuistle Sorry for not being clear, i am using SWT not Swings.

Comment: @nik7 Mind changing the accepted answer to the other one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the height in pixels:

```
/* Set the height to 75 pixels */
data.heightHint = 75;
```

However, you can also set the height in terms of the number of character rows, but you have to do some trickery to measure the character height.  You'll need to build a graphics context (`GC`) to measure the text extent.

For example:

```
GC gc = new GC(text);
try
{
    gc.setFont(text.getFont());
    FontMetrics fm = gc.getFontMetrics();

    /* Set the height to 5 rows of characters */
    data.heightHint = 5 * fm.getHeight();
}
finally
{
    gc.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. also for others we can also use widthHint  property for setting the width.

Answer (score 30):

You can also use [Text.getLineHeight()](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Text.html&anchor=getLineHeight%28%29) to determine the height of a single line of text, you don't need a GC for that:

```
final Text text = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP);
GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false);
gridData.heightHint = 5 * text.getLineHeight();
text.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

Comment: +1 Good point and very clean solution! @nik7 Please consider accepting this answer instead.

Comment: This solution is much more cleaner than the accepted one. Easier and faster to implement.